# Differentiating between free PS+ games and purchased games

Tags: ps4, psn

I recently was given a promo code to redeem a game on my PS4, and before redeeming it, I checked my library and noticed that the game I was about to redeem was already listed there. I can't remember if the game was one that I purchased, or downloaded for free through my PS+ subscription.

Is there any way to tell, *on the console itself*, if a game in the PS4 library was downloaded for free through PS+? Or is the only way to look through one's purchase history online and pick out the ones that cost nothing?

I ask because if the game is from my PS+ subscription, I'd like to still redeem the code, as I would like the game to be available after my subscription has expired. Otherwise, I'll hold off on redeeming the key.

Comment: What would you do with the key btw, give it away?

Comment: @djsmiley, Probably. I'd need to check if it's legal to do so first. Not particularly relevant.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind to me is that you could check if the licence for the game expires (select the game tile, press options and then information). If the game licence expires at the same time as your plus subscription it has to be a plus game. I can't check right now but it might be that the licence tab only shows for such games anyway or maybe for purchased games it shows "no expiration" or something.

Comment: @Kodama That works! For PS+ games, it shows "Valid Period" and "Remaining Time", and on my purchased games those fields don't show up at all. Only drawback is that it seems you can only view the "Information" menu on installed games (unless there's something I'm missing). Please post as an answer so I can give you some rep!

Comment: finally got around to it... :) Just out of curiosity: Did you have the promo code game already as Plus and did you try to redeem the code? As far as I know you can't buy games you already have as Plus games because there is no buying option as you already "own" the game. It would be interesting to know if you can get around purchasing a Plus game by buying a code elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't try redeeming it yet, as it ends up that I _had_ bought the game in question. I'm curious as well, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can go to your Library and PS+ games will be listed there in the separate group:

[image: Library screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

The only way to check if a game on your PS4 is a Plus game is to see if the game has an expiring licence. Plus games have a licence ending at the same time as your Plus subscription, while purchased games don't.

To see if your game has an expiring licence select the game tile, press the options button and select "Information". A PS Plus game will show lines for "Valid Period (Start)/(End)" and "Remaining Time", while purchased games don't have these lines.